# ASP.net Core 2.0 cant find services.AddSession();

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

How can I use sessions in ASP.net Core 2.0? Im using HttpContext.Session.GetString(); But that does not save to the session because I need to configure Startup.cs so that I can use session.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session Nuget package and then add support for sessions in `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        options.CookieHttpOnly = true;
    });
```

See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add sessions as a service in **startup.cs** file.

Remember to add it before `services.AddMvc();` [Go to this link for all the details.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/session-state-in-asp-net-core/)

Since there is no project.json in visual studio 2017, you can skip that part.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register Session in service configuration -

```
  services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.CookieHttpOnly = true;
            });
```

To use it anywhere inject in the constructor. Here I am using a controller constructor for demonstration -

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

 public class AccountController : Controller
    { 
      private ISession _session;
      public AccountController( IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
         {
            _session = contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;
         }
    }
```

Now to Get and Set value in session to simplify my purpose; I used an extension method below -

```
public static class HttpSessionExtension
    {
        public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
        {
            session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
        }

        public static T Get<T>(this ISession session, string key)
        {
            var value = session.GetString(key);
            return value == null ? default(T) :
                                  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
        }
    }
```

The usage is simple -

```
_session.Set<MyModel>(Mykey, value);
_session.Get<MyModel>(Mykey);
```